# How to create an aggregate fat jar from super pom file?

Tags: java, maven-3, parent-pom

I have an aggregate maven module that is a multi module maven project consisting of a super POM. This aggregate module consists of several sub maven projects. In the super POM of the aggregate module, I have included the jar dependencies that are common for the sub-projects. In the POM file of each sub-project, I have included the jars that are only specific to these projects.

The super POM looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.testproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>../../Projects/ProjectA</module>
        <module>../../Projects/ProjectB</module>
        <module>../../Projects/ProjectC</module>
    </modules>
   <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.swinglabs.swingx</groupId>
    <artifactId>swingx-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdesktop</groupId>
    <artifactId>swing-layout</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

**An important note is that my aggregate module contains no source code, but just the super POM. Hence there is no main class as well and therefore I cannot use the Maven Assembly Plugin. My main class is in one of the sub-projects.**

How can I create a jar file out of the super POM of the aggregate module?

The reason why I would like to get a jar from the POM file is that I would like to continue using ant for the build process.

My expectation is that the final jar from the super POM contains all the dependent jars like junit, swingx-core, swing-layout etc as one fat jar 
that I can include in the ant build process.

Is this possible with maven? Am I missing something?

I have tried to change the packaging from pom to jar but I get a compile error on mvn-install saying "packaging with jar is invalid. Aggregator projects require 'pom' as packaging".

mvn-install and mvn-compile work fine when I use packaging as pom.

Comment: Maybe the maven shade plugin? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: @Cristian Ramon-Cortes:Also requires a main class like: <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>org.sonatype.haven.HavenCli</mainClass>
                </transformer>